# Can I stack pots while cooking?

Tags: pan, frying-pan, pot, induction

I have a one-burner induction cooktop and I use a stainless steel pot to cook various things, like rice and spaghetti. But I always get burnt rice or food stuck to the bottom of the pot, regardless of the heat level, and even if I put it on the lowest heat. It seems to me the reason could be the stainless steel pot has a very thin bottom. And I thought maybe I could solve this by cooking with another frying pan beneath the pot.

Is that a viable solution to my problem? Can I put the frying pan which has a thick bottom on the induction cooktop and stack the stainless pot on top of it?

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend it. The heat transfer is going to be abysmal, and "overheating" the empty pan to indirectly heat the pot is eventually going to damage the pan as well. Get a solid, heavy stainless pot; it doesn't need to be super expensive. Even the ones from IKEA's medium price tier are going to be okay.

Answer (score 3):

This is indeed a common problem with induction, especially if you are cooking small quantities.

You can certainly do what you propose, but you'll have to choose a pan which won't be damaged - the best would be a stainless steel pan without any coatings. Other types would work too, but certainly no nonstick pans.

At that point, you are practically misusing the pan as a converter disc, so you can just go and buy a real one, it will be much more convenient.